# How to use luxon Datetime.fromFormat when time zone is in the date string?

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

We have run into a bug in our UI using luxon.DateTime.  currently the code looks like this:

```
DateTime.fromFormat(input, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'TT 'GMT'").toFormat(format);
```

The problem is that this is explicitly looking for GMT time.  We also get UTC times and when that happens the code fails to generate a proper time.

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to specify the section of the input time that corresponds to 'GMT' or 'UTC' should be treated as a zone.

The best option I could come up with is a regex to pull out the zone from the input string, and then specify it in the options passed to fromFormat, but that seems cumbersome.  Surely there is a cleaner solution I'm just too incompetent to find in the luxon API?

...this would be so much easier if the backend just passed us Linux time instead of a random string for a timestamp.  Linux time is your friend people, use it!

Comment: Is the issue that you only want to accept GMT/UTC times, and reject anything else? Or would you be okay with parsing any input timezone at all? (Please note that a trailing Z is another way UTC time is often formatted.)

Comment: @kshetline I'd like to accept any timezones, so we don't get a new bug as soon as someone tries to pass us a different one.  If I just wanted UTC or GMT I'd probably be lazy and do an if statement

Comment: The Luxon 'z' token will parse IANA timezone names, like "America/New_York". UTC and GMT are valid IANA zones, so those will parse too. Some timezone abbreviations, however, aren't IANA zones, or aren't unambiguous, so you have to be careful with those. For example, EST works, but EDT doesn't.

Comment: @dsollen are you able to get around this issue? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @naren no sorry.  I was asking this question for a friend who was working on the bug, but our contracts diverged and I lost contact with him so I'm not sure his solution, though I suspect he hard coded it.  I mostly was asking because hearing him say he was planning to hard code it made my eye twitch ;) :P

Comment: I asked similar question. I ended up changing the format based on the reply here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622589/issue-with-luxon-date-time-parsing-when-zone-is-present-in-string